# Does repeated vertex in polygon definition makes it self-intersecting?

Tags: geometry, polygons

If we consider polygon definition as list of connected vertices (where we don't have sequences of same repeated points) and we have equal vertices (with same coordinates) in different position
$$
P = (v_0, v_1, \dots, v_M) \quad \exists i, j \in \{0, \dots, M\}: P_i = P_j
$$
-- is it enough to conclude that polygon is self-intersecting? I cannot think of counterexample and it seems kind of obvious, so I have thought there should be some related lemma/theorem or a logical proof.

Comment: It depends on your definitions. Is listing the vertices simply a way to define a polygonal line, that is, a subset of the plane? Or does it define a paramedic curve? if so, how?

Comment: My point is, does $j=i+1$ imply a self-intersection? When $P_i$ and $P_j$ are clearly separated with other different vertices between them, then yes, it is a self-intersection.

Comment: @lhf: $i \ne (j + 1) \% M$ and $j \ne (i + 1) \% M$, because it will be a "sequence of same repeated point", so no extra repetitions

Comment: @lhf: yes, I'm defining polygon given coordinates of its line endpoints (at least it is a common practice in computer geometry I'm working on)